# Почему в опциях "фрагмента кода" нельзя подключить bootstrap?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, сниппеты

Почему в опциях "фрагмента кода" нет возможности подключить `bootstrap`? Разве он не занимает должное распространение среди фреймверков и библиотек, которые есть в опциях?

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всё равно тут всё несвежее...

Comment: @Qwertiy а это сайт разработчики просматривают?? желание "форумчан" выполняют хотябы тогда, когда эти желания адекватные?

Comment: Так ведь с cdn можно любой скрипт указать самому.

Comment: @Qwertiy но пару раз клацнуть мышкой на много удобнее, согласитесь.

Comment: Вероятно потому, что Bootstrap - это не js-фреймворк.

Comment: @Sergeygornostaev т е ваше мнение что если это не js фреймворком, то ему не место в списке? И там же написано "опции" а опциями может быть даже выбор препроцессор, но об этом уже умалкиваю...

Comment: Вообще конечно было бы полезно, если бы можно было добавлять ещё и css фреймворки. Но думаю это надо писать разбарам.

Comment: Такой же запрос на en.SO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294365/help-us-easily-create-twitter-bootstrap-stack-snippets и на meta.SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239581/add-bootstrap-to-available-external-libraries Реализовывать вроде не собираются, т.к. ссылки легко вставить самому

Comment: @defaultlocale если дело пошло за "легче", то jQuery ещё легче подключить, но она там есть.

Comment: если кликнуть "добавить внешнюю библиотеку", то fontawesome.css вполне добавился... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/957428/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0/957495#957495

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц это не мнение о том как должно быть, а объяснение почему сейчас так. Все имеющиеся сейчас селекты относятся к js-фреймворкам, видать, разработчики SO считали, что css-фреймворки не нужны или видели какие-то проблемы с подключением стилей на лету.